# How to correctly select default option in list?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 6 lists whiich i populate via script. 
Im using angular js and my html looks like this:

```
                 <div class="advancedSearch hidden">
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                       <select name="number" ng-model="Numbers" ng-change="listSearchChnage(Numbers, 'number')" class="form-control" >
                          <option value="">Choose Nummer</option>
                          <option  ng:repeat="number in Numbers" value="{{number}}">{{number}}</option>
                          <!-- Select month -->
                      </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <select name="objDesc" class="form-control" ng-model="ObjektDescriptions" ng-change="listSearchChnage(ObjektDescriptions,'objektDescription')">
                            <option value="">Choose something</option>
                            <option  ng:repeat="desc in ObjektDescriptions" value="{{desc}}">{{desc}}</option>
                            <!-- Select month -->
                        </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <select name="tenantName" class="form-control" ng-model="CustomerNames" ng-change="listSearchChnage(CustomerNames,'customerName')" >
                            <option value="">Choose somethingelse</option>
                            <option  ng:repeat="customerName in CustomerNames" value="{{customerName}}">{{customerName}}</option>

                        </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <select name="dateSearch" class="form-control" ng-model="RegisterDates" ng-change="listSearchChnage(RegisterDates,'registerDate')" >
                            <option value="">Choose somethingelse</option>
                            <option  ng:repeat="date in RegisterDates" value="{{date}}">{{date}}</option>
                            <!-- Select month -->
                        </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <select name="managerSearch" class="form-control" ng-model="Managers" ng-change="listSearchChnage(Managers,'manager')">
                            <option value="">Choose somethingelse</option>
                            <option  ng:repeat="manager in Managers" value="{{status}}">{{manager}}</option>
                            <!-- Select month -->
                        </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <select name="advStatusSearch" class="form-control" ng-model="AdvStatuses" ng-change="listSearchChnage(AdvStatuses,'s')">
                            <option value="">Choose Status</option>
                            <option  ng:repeat="s in AdvStatuses" value="{{s}}">{{s}}</option>
                            <!-- Select month -->
                        </select>
                     </div>
```

Script:

```
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        $scope.Numbers.push(v.orderraderid);

        if ($.inArray($.trim(v.orderraderid), $scope.Numbers) == -1)
            $scope.Numbers.push(v.orderraderid);

            if ($.inArray($.trim(v.objektbeteckning), $scope.ObjektDescriptions) == -1)
                $scope.ObjektDescriptions.push(v.objektbeteckning);

            if ($.inArray(v.kundnamn, $scope.CustomerNames) == -1)
                $scope.CustomerNames.push(v.kundnamn);

            if ($.inArray(v.anmdatum, $scope.RegisterDates) == -1) 
                $scope.RegisterDates.push(v.anmdatum);

            if ($.inArray($.trim(v.status), $scope.AdvStatuses) == -1)
                $scope.AdvStatuses.push(v.status);

            if ($.inArray($.trim(v.utforare), $scope.Managers) == -1)
                $scope.Managers.push(v.utforare);
    });
```

All lists except the last one that renders the "status" get their first option selected as default.

Ive tried hardcoding the the select attribute "selected=selected" but that did not work. Ive even tried setting it via script like so:

```
$(".advancedSearch select option").each(function () {
                   $(this).removeAttr('selected');
               });
```

but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while but i changed from

```
 <option  ng:repeat="status in AdvStatuses" value="{{status}}">{{status}}</option>
```

To

```
 <option  ng:repeat="status in AdvStatuses" value="">{{status}}</option>
```

And it solved the problem. I don't really understand why this happened and would appreciate an explenation if anyone has one?